# Sci-Fi movie about a shapeshifter

Tags: story-identification, movie, shape-shifter

I've seen a small portion of this movie roughly 15 years ago. Unfortunately, I was really young and can't really remember a lot of the details. I'd be really happy if you could help me identify it.

- People are out in the wilderness, they set up a camp
- They return to it and see their camp destroyed by what they think must have been a bear
- The shapeshifter turns into a person that's been killed
- They face the shapeshifter in a labyrinth-like ruin where it hid
- It's revealed that the shapeshifter's looks are influenced by people's thoughts
- They kill the shapeshifter by thinking of it dying from electricity
- After their trip, when one of the characters is back at home, the shapeshifter reappears in front of the window in the form in which they killed it

It was in color and I think that it looked a little dated, even at the time, so I'd date it roughly to the 1980s.

Again, because I was very young, some of the details could be different. The place where they were facing the shapeshifter could've been a normal house that was just too complicated for my young mind.

Comment: The creature reminds me a little bit of the creature in Forbidden Planet, whose appearance was also influenced by the protagonists.

Comment: From the first 4 points I was going to suggest [The Thing (1982)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084787/) but from then on they start to become less of a match...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"High Desert Kill" (1989 TV movie)?

Here is a plot summary from IMDb:

> Like every year, Jim, Ray, Brad and Paul leave the town for a week
>   to go hunting in the woods. But this year everything is different:
>   There's not a single animal to be found, the whole forest has fallen
>   quiet. Two female campers they meet have mysteriously disappeared the
>   next day, leaving their whole equipment behind. And then they start to
>   behave weird themselves... An alien power is using them for cruel
>   psychological experiments.

Here is the entire movie from YouTube,the scene with the shape-shifter appearing in a window in the form of a character who had died earlier starts at 1:29:00.

Comment: I‘ve looked at the scene starting at 1:29 and it looks very much like what I had in mind. Thanks! I‘ll check the movie out soon and confirm this then.

Comment: @John: Did you ever get a chance to verify this?

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten about this post altogether. I did get around to watch it and it was exactly what I remembered. Huge thank you!